# Tengo un problema con interfaz grafica, el JLabel se repite dos veces a pesar de que solo tengo uno

Tags: java, bluej, jlabel

Este es todo el código:

```js
  
public class pruebadibujo2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel ima;
    public static void main (String agrs[]) {
        marco aaa = new marco();
        aaa.setVisible(true);
        aaa.setResizable(false);
        aaa.setBounds(300,100,800,570);
    }

    public pruebadibujo2(){
        setTitle("Prueba");
        lamina lla=new lamina();
        add(lla);
        
        ima = new JLabel("Peliculas");
        ima.setBounds(120,10,350,30);
        ima.setFont(new Font ("Roboto",Font.BOLD,18));
        add(ima);
    }

> Aqui tengo declarado el JLabel no se porque se repite 2 veces antes lo tenia declarado en un jPanel pero luego lo cambie y puse el JFrame en el public class
```

Comment: Qué es marco(), qué es lamina(), o qué llama a pruebadibujo2() y publique también una imagen del JLabel que se está duplicando. Basado solo en este fragmento de código, lo más probable es que su constructor sea llamado dos veces, pero no podemos estar seguros porque necesitamos más código para verificar.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, el problema era marco y lamina, aunque no se porque compilaba si lamina y marco no existían son dos clases que borre sin embargo nunca salto un error, de nuevo gracias el jLabel ya no se repite.